# Getting the elementid value in order to toggle menus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to toggle the content shown on a page given a menu on top using javascript (could do jquery but not really sure how):

javascript

```
function showhidediv(rad) {
    document.getElementById("general_item").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("specific_item").style.display = "none";
    var sectionName = rad.value;
    document.getElementById(sectionName+'_section').style.display = "block"; 
}
```

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li value="general" onclick="showhidediv(this);">General</li>
  <li value="specific" onclick="showhidediv(this);">Specific</li>
</ul>
```

My two sections are #general_section and #specific_section.

It seems like I am not able to get the value of the < li > that was clicked, keeps on giving the value '0'.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had used wrong `id` attributes to hide the elements

without jQuery

```
<ul>
  <li section="general" onclick="showhidediv(this);">General</li>
  <li section="specific" onclick="showhidediv(this);">Specific</li>
</ul>
<div id="general_section">general</div>
<div id="specific_section">specific</div>
```

and

```
function showhidediv(rad) {
    document.getElementById("general_section").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("specific_section").style.display = "none";
    var sectionName = rad.getAttribute('section');
    document.getElementById(sectionName+'_section').style.display = "block"; 
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PmSVe/)

Comment: Thanks that worked... will accept the answer as soon as it allows me

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<ul id="tabs">
  <li tab-content="general">General</li>
  <li tab-content="specific">Specific</li>
</ul>

<div class="contents" id="general" style="display: none">it is general tab</div>
<div class="contents" id="specific">it is Specific tab</div>
```

JS (jQuery)

```
$('#tabs li').click(function(){
    $('.contents').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).attr('tab-content')).show();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/_smakii_/GHWr9/)